# How to show error outside catch found in catch block in php

Tags: php, exception

I have situation and i need to show error that is caught in an exception and i want to show or use  that error outside catch() block
My code is

```
$error;
try {

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                                               "description"=>"Customer",
                                               "source" => $token,
                                               "email" => $email,
                                               "plan" => "armorax"
                                               )
                                         );

    $payment = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                                            'amount'        => $amount,
                                            'currency'      => 'usd',

                                            'description'   => $_POST['description'],
                                            "customer" => $customer->id

                                            )
                                      );

}
catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

    $body = $e->getJsonBody();
    $err  = $body['error'];
    $error= 'Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n";
    //If i use print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus()) then error is get printed here but i don't need to print error here. 
}

//SOme HTML CODE I want to show error below but it is not showing here
<div class="alert"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
```

I want to show $error outside the catch block as shown in above example but it is not printing any error

Please help

Comment: What you've got should work. You should put `$error = ""` before the `try` statement. BTW, why aren't you doing anything with `$err`?

Comment: Just to make sure, before the `try` do this `$error = 'no error'` and run your script

Comment: Is the HTML code in the same function as the `try` statement?

Comment: Hello.
No Html is outside the function,, I am having try catch inside a function and i want to print error outside that functions
i have already used $error="", $error="null" before try and also tried before function ()

Comment: You should `return $error` from the function, and use `$error = functionName(...)`.

Comment: And you should learn about variable scope in PHP.

Comment: yes. return $error worked fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable:

```
$GLOBALS['myError'] = "Status is:" . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n";
```

Then:

```
<div class="alert"><?php echo $GLOBALS['myError']; ?></div>
```

---

Or simply:

```
global $error = "Status is:" . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n";
```

Then:

```
<div class="alert"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
```

---

Learn more about Global Variables and Scope of Variables in PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: This shouldn't be needed unless they're in different functions.

Comment: @Barmar The rest of the code is unknown to me, so, using `$GLOBALS`  may fix the OP problem.

Comment: Then ask the OP for more details. At least explain the circumstances where this change is needed, like if they're in different functions.

Comment: Hello @Barmar  i used $GLOBALS but it is not working also. 
another thing is i am having catch inside a function and then i am printing errors outside that function.

Comment: Then `$GLOBALS` should work. Or put `global $error;` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using globals you could just pre-define a variable for the exception outside of the try-catch block:

```
$ex = null;
try {
  throw new Exception('Exception thrown inside the try-catch block');
} catch (Throwable $ex) {
 // Empty catch to save the exception.
}

if (!is_null($ex)) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Note that the variable is not necessary to modify the scope but instead call `is_null` without getting a PHP notice.
Use `php -a` to run the code locally.
I used `7.3.19`